# Как сравнить две строки

Tags: mysql, sql, алгоритм, строки, поиск

Мне нужно понять, насколько две фразы похожи друг на друга, получить меру их соответствия. Например, есть поисковая фраза

```
Магазин - Кухня "Латте" (тип 1) ПМ 115.01 Шкаф настенный с 1 дверью
```

и список фраз

1. `Настенный шкаф «Киви» ПМ-139.11`
2. `Шкаф настенный с 1-ой дверью «Латте-1» ПМ-115.01`
3. `Шкаф настенный с 1-ой дверью «Латте-2» ПМ-115.01`

Как мне понять в коде, что поисковой фразе наиболее соответствует фраза 2?
MATCH AGAINST запрос в Mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE MATCH (body) AGAINST ('Магазин - Кухня "Латте" (тип 1) ПМ 115.01 Шкаф настенный с 1 дверью');
```

ничего не возвращает. Может существуют какие-нибудь алгоритмы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы начал с рассмотрения [Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) и дальше по ссылкам. Вполне возможно, что это то, что Вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Это довольно сложный вопрос. В вашем случае вы полагаетесь на ключевые слова, поэтому подход вроде скалярного произведения векторов, полученных с помощью TF-IDF, кажется мне хорошим началом.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TF-IDF